# ¿Como agrupar valores repetidos de un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, jsonarray

tengo una api  en nodejs que realiza una consulta a base de datos y me devuelve un array, lo que quiero es agrupar los valores repetidos del array

```
async function getPersonal(data) {
    try {
        let pool = await mssql.connect(config);
        var procedimiento = await pool.request()
            .input('id', mssql.Int, data.id)     
            .execute('ejecutoProcedimientoAlmacenado');
            datos = procedimiento.recordsets[0];
        return datos;

    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

que me devuelve el siguiente array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "apellidoPat": "Campos",
        "apellidoMat": "Meza",
        "nombre": "Juan",
        "fecha": "01-04-2022",
        "observacion": "llego temprano"
    },
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "apellidoPat": "Campos",
        "apellidoMat": "Meza",
        "nombre": "Juan",
        "fecha": "02-04-2022",
        "observacion": "llego tarde"
    }
]
```

y quiero agrupar objetos repetidos, Como pueden ver, los valores de **id**, **apellidoPat**, **apellidoMat**, **nombre** están repetidos y necesito agruparlo de la siguente manera:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "apellidoPat": "Campos",
        "apellidoMat": "Meza",
        "nombre": "Juan",
        "data": [
            {
                "fecha": "01-04-2022",
                "observacion": "llego temprano"
            },
            {
                "fecha": "02-04-2022",
                "observacion": "llego tarde"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

agradesco desde ya sus ayuda.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte. Por favor agrega lo que has intentado hacer aunque no funcione, las preguntas que no muestran un esfuerzo terminan cerradas y/o votadas negativamente.

Comment: Christian... Qué palabras utilizaste para buscar en google? Yo escribí "agrupar javascript" y casi todas las sugerencias de la primera página resuelven el problema. Incluso, cuatro de ellas son de **este mismo sitio**. Tal vez si usas la barra de búsqueda puedas encontrar una solución.

Comment: busca en ingles

Comment: Por ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776389/javascript-object-grouping

Comment: si busqué en google, pero no es como lo necesito, si se fija bien al final de mi pregunta muestro lo que necesito hacer, en otros ejemplos agrupan deferente a mi necesidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente haya una forma mas optimizada, podes hacer algo así:

- un forEach recorre los elementos del array de entrada
- a cada elemento lo desestructuramos en variables:

  - id, apellidoPat, apellidoMat, nombre, y el resto de cosas va en data
- un find busca si ya hay un registro con ese id en el array de salida

  - si existe ese elemento le agregamos data al array data
  - si no existe el elemento agregamos al array de salida las variables previamente desestructuradas transformando data en un array

```js
let a = [{
    "id": 1234,
    "apellidoPat": "Campos",
    "apellidoMat": "Meza",
    "nombre": "Juan",
    "fecha": "01-04-2022",
    "observacion": "llego temprano"
  },
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "apellidoPat": "Campos",
    "apellidoMat": "Meza",
    "nombre": "Juan",
    "fecha": "02-04-2022",
    "observacion": "llego tarde"
  },
  {
    "id": 1244,
    "apellidoPat": "Rutas",
    "apellidoMat": "Zilla",
    "nombre": "Pedro",
    "fecha": "02-04-2022",
    "observacion": "llego tarde"
  }
]
let o = []

a.forEach((e) => {
  ({
    id,
    apellidoPat,
    apellidoMat,
    nombre,
    ...data
  } = e)
  let d = o.find((x) => e.id == x.id)
  if (d) {
    d.data.push(data)
  } else {

    o.push({
      id,
      apellidoPat,
      apellidoMat,
      nombre,
      data: [data]
    })
  }
})
console.log(o)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, si me funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Se podría recurrir a utilizar un `reduce` para agrupar de la manera que quieres y tomando como base el array original que adjuntabas en la pregunta y añadiendo un nuevo item para comprobar que no se solapan. Se podrá solucionar utilizando:

```js
const originalArray = [
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "apellidoPat": "Campos",
        "apellidoMat": "Meza",
        "nombre": "Juan",
        "fecha": "01-04-2022",
        "observacion": "llego temprano"
    },
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "apellidoPat": "Campos",
        "apellidoMat": "Meza",
        "nombre": "Juan",
        "fecha": "02-04-2022",
        "observacion": "llego tarde"
    },
    {
        "id": 1244,
        "apellidoPat": "Mesa",
        "apellidoMat": "Gonzalez",
        "nombre": "David",
        "fecha": "02-04-2022",
        "observacion": "llego tarde"
    }
];

function groupById(array) {
    return array.reduce((acc, current) => {
        const foundItem = acc.find(it => it.id === current.id);

        if (foundItem) {
            foundItem.data = foundItem.data
                ? [...foundItem.data, { 'fecha': current.fecha, 'observacion': current.observacion }]
                : [{ 'fecha': current.fecha, 'observacion': current.observacion }];
        } else { 
            acc.push({
                'id': current.id,
                'apellidoPat': current.apellidoPat,
                'apellidoMat': current.apellidoMat,
                'nombre': current.nombre,
                'data': [{ 'fecha': current.fecha, 'observacion': current.observacion }]
            });
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
}

console.log(groupById(originalArray));
```

Lo cual devuelve un array como este:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "apellidoPat": "Campos",
    "apellidoMat": "Meza",
    "nombre": "Juan",
    "data": [
      {
        "fecha": "01-04-2022",
        "observacion": "llego temprano"
      },
      {
        "fecha": "02-04-2022",
        "observacion": "llego tarde"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1244,
    "apellidoPat": "Mesa",
    "apellidoMat": "Gonzalez",
    "nombre": "David",
    "data": [
      {
        "fecha": "02-04-2022",
        "observacion": "llego tarde"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

A mi de esta manera me funciona.

```
    const distinctIds = [];
    originalArray.forEach(entry =>{
        const {id, apellidoMat, apellidoPat, nombre, fecha, observacion} = entry;
        const data = {fecha, observacion};
        const exists = distinctIds.find(y => y.id === entry.id)
        if (!exists){
            distinctIds.push({id, apellidoMat, apellidoPat, nombre, data: [data]})
        }else {
            exists.data.push(data)
        }
    } )
```

Comment: muchas gracias.